# Node js: spawn process catch exception/error

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, spawn

I am trying to run a c++ executable using spawn process. Here is c++ code of the executable:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void divide(int num1, int num2) {
    // Complete this function
    cout << num1/num2;

}

int main(){
    int num1, num2;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    divide(num1, num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is code for nodejs

```
var bat = spawn(filePath);

bat.stdin.write("6\n");
bat.stdin.write("0\n");

bat.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("Output: ", data.toString());
});
bat.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("Error: ", data.toString());
});
bat.once('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
    return;
});
```

I am unable to catch "division by zero" exception using this code. What is missing in this code? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
bat.once('exit', function (code) {
```

Try:

```
bat.on('close', function (code) {
```

Comment: Please post your complete node.js file. For example, in the snippet you posted above, you are missing a "require" for spawn.